# Required String parameter 'redirect_uri' is not present in Cognito Federated IDP Flow in React.js

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

After successful login from microsoft website below error is shown.

Record is being created in cognito with external provider as confirmation status.

[image]

**Below is my sample code and amplify config**

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        userPoolWebClientId: 'xyz',
        userPoolId: 'xyz',
        region: 'us-east-1',
        oauth: {
            domain: 'xyz.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
            scope: ['aws.cognito.signin.user.admin', 'email', 'openid', 'profile', 'phone'],
            redirectSignIn: 'https://stdev.net/',
            redirectSignOut: 'https://stdev.net/logout',
            responseType: 'CODE'
        }
    }
});


Auth.federatedSignIn({ customProvider: 'AzureProviderId' });
```